# Data Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here is my current code:

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim firstemployee As String
Dim secondemployee As String
firstemployee = DLookup("[empName]", "[TempTable]", "[ID] = 1")
secondemployee = DLookup("[empName]", "[TempTable]", "[ID] = 2")
SQL = "INSERT INTO [Weeks on Call]([Primary Employee], [Backup Employee]," & _
      " [Week]) VALUES ('" + firstemployee + "','" + secondemployee + "'," & _
      "#" + firstDate + "#)"
```

Primary Employee in the table is a Text field,

Backup is a Text field,

Week is a Date/Time field

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Could someone please take a quick look at it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using Chr(35) instead of #? I have had issues in the past because of this. Not sure of SQL syntax though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not see you assigning values any of the variables. Try the following.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim firstemployee As String
Dim secondemployee As String

firstDate = Date()
firstemployee = "Santa"
secondemployee = "Aimonce"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Weeks on Call] ([Primary Employee], [Backup Employee], [Week]) " & _
      "VALUES ('" & firstemployee & "', '" & secondemployee & "', " & Format(firstDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & ")"
Debug.Print strSQL
```

See what you get printed in the immediate window. It should help you with the debugging.

Comment: sorry I forgot to include that code! but anyways i found the issue was with the format of the date. I copy pasted the code you had over and it worked. Thanks!